# Make a button active at a particular hour

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface, time

I want a button that will become available at, say, 8 AM. I know how to check if the button is available when the view is loaded, but, if the user is looking at the button as the clock turns to 8 AM, how do I get the button to become active without loading the view?

Comment: Setup an `NSTimer` to go off at the desired time and update the button as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button should always be present. Use its `hidden` to hide and show it as necessary. Or you can use its `enabled` to enable or disable it as necessary, but this can require more work, because a disabled button might not automatically *look* disabled so the user won't understand that it isn't truly "available".

Thus we have three cases to deal with:

- The user moves to this view controller, the view controller loads its view, and your code decides about the button state / visibility *now*. You've already handled this one.
- The view controller is already present and the view is visible, and the availability-change moment comes. In this case you will need previously to have set up a notification to prompt the view controller to take action now. *Do not loop perpetually* watching the time. Use an NSTimer or similar (a local notification is also worth considering).
- The view controller is covered by another view controller and then uncovered. Perhaps the state needs to have changed in the meantime. So you will also want to do this check generally in `viewWillAppear:`, not just in `viewDidLoad`.